# Dynamodb query returns json with synthax error

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Connected to dynamoDb table using Nodejs, i want to fetch items from table. i tried using query option, it returns json with items but some times it returns Json with synthax error

This is  my code

```
let ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB(config)
export const dynamoDb = ddb
export const dynamoClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
  service: dynamoDb
})

let params = {
    TableName: auditTable,
    IndexName: 'importId-auditStatus-index',
    KeyConditionExpression: 'importId = :importId and auditStatus = :auditStatus',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':importId': importId,
      ':auditStatus' : 'Imported'
    }
  }

let response = await dynamoClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
    } else {
      return data;
    }
  }).promise();
  console.log("response",response)
```

Some times it returns Json with synthax error as given below

{
"Count":117,
"Items":[
... truncated by me ...
{
"pricingTemplate":{
"NULL":true
},
"auditId":{
"S":"7555555_15287101"
},
"importId":{
"S":"8c6976bb-8680-47ce-bcfb-470c8e97740f"
},
"auditStatus":{
"S":"Imported"
},
"Id":{
"S":"420f50cb-3d03-49cb-b1da-1a36aa099e6c"
},
"recordType":{
"S":"currecy_test_tl"
}
}
,{"pricingTemplate":{"NULL":true},"auditId":{"S":"7555555_15287164"},"importId":{"S":"8c6976bb-8680-47ce-bcfb-470c8e97740f"},"auditStatus":{"S":"Imported"}7555555_15287206"},"importId":{"S":"8c6976bb-8680-47ce-bcfb-470c8e97740f"},"auditStatus":{"S":"Imported"},"Id":{"S":"e7042719-fa77-4939-9d05-ad41f3bdc7dc"},"recordType":{"S":"currecy_test_tl"}},{"pricingTemplate":{"NULL":true},"auditId":{"S":"7555555_15287155"},"importId":{"S":"8c6976bb-8680-47ce-bcfb-470c8e97740f"},"auditStatus":{"S":"Imported"},"Id":{"S":"bee5d2e3-60cf-4ecf-8249-d25de6e8c28a"},"recordType":{"S":"currecy_test_tl"}},
{
"pricingTemplate":{
"NULL":true
},
"auditId":{
"S":"7555555_15287111"
},
"importId":{
"S":"8c6976bb-8680-47ce-bcfb-470c8e97740f"
},
"auditStatus":{
"S":"Imported"
},
"Id":{
"S":"2161a17f-63c5-4c45-b7b4-9750cc202b23"
},
"recordType":{
"S":"currecy_test_tl"
}
}
],
"ScannedCount":117
}

Edits:
Syntax error at `auditStatus":{"S":"Imported"}7555555_15287206"},`

Comment: where is the error?

Comment: I guess u mean: `"S":"Imported"` ? the `S` says it is a String, if that is the problem, you need to `unmarshall` the response

Comment: You mean `auditStatus":{"S":"Imported"}7555555_15287206"},`?

Comment: @derpirscher yes `auditStatus":{"S":"Imported"}7555555_15287206"},` is the issue.

cc: @Woohaik

Comment: @Woohaik i dont think the issue is with the `"Imported"`

Comment: Can you reproduce this consistently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you're sharing and the output you shared are not aligned. The Document Client `dynamoClient` which you use in the code returns native JSON. The low level client `dynamoDb` and `ddb` in your code will return DynamoDB JSON, which is what you are outputting and calling a syntax error.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypeDescriptors

Comment: `auditStatus":{"S":"Imported"}7555555_15287206"}` please check this line.